# Dynamic_sidebar load in string makeup

Tags: php, widgets

In my Wordpress theme the header is loaded through a string example below, i wish to be able to load a dynamic sidebar (widget) in it but its not working and only showing on front-end the number '1' where it should be loaded.

can anyone help with how to load a sidebar in the string makeup?

`$menu_markup = '<header class="%s header"> '. dynamic_sidebar('header-widget').'  </div>`

Comment: @michael please check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to catch the display of the sidebar. This does make it a bit more difficult to debug should you need to but it will get you what you need:

```
ob_start();

    dynamic_sidebar( 'header-widget' );

$sidebar        = ob_get_clean();
$menu_markup    = '<header class="%s header">' . $sidebar . '</div>';
```

Comment: thanks, that did work but i should have mentioned that there is more variables being used in the markup! i've pasted the hole code in PasteBin link below... how can i use your code when there is more %s  https://pastebin.com/mXtbaKeg

Comment: @dan You can still use the code above. In my example, the whole sidebar HTML is now held in the `$sidebar` as a string variable. You can plug it into your string or do whatever you need to.